# Cómo comparo minutos en MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Tengo un campo con un timestamp con el valor 2020-01-01T14:18:03-06:00
Tengo otro campo con la hora solamente, es un texto con la hora 14:00
lo que necesito es comparar la hora que está en el timestamp con la hora del otro campo + 15 min
para esto estoy utilizando el siguiente código,

```
if(timestampdiff(MINUTE,date_format(tracked_arrival, '%H:%i'),ADDTIME(str_to_date(time_window_end, '%H:%i'),'00:15'))>=0, 1,0) as "a"
```

Pero no me funciona, 
tienen alguna opción?

también utilice ya

```
if(Timediff(date_format(tracked_arrival, '%H:%i'),ADDTIME(str_to_date(time_window_end, '%H:%i'),'00:15:00'))>='00:00', 1 else NULL) as "a"
```

Ninguna de las dos me funciona, 
alguna idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar la funcion `TIME()` de MySQL la cual te va a regresar el tiempo de un elemento  y usar la funcion `ADDTIME()` la cual va a sumar tiempo a un elemento.

La logica es simple vamos a tener

`TIME(timestamp1)`

y

`TIME(ADDTIME(timestamp2, "00:15:00"))`

Fijate que la segunda sentencia es una mezcla de `TIME()` y `ADDTIME()` ya que solo queremos regresar la hora exacta con minutos y segundo, ademas de eso ve que la funcion `ADDTIME(timeOriginal,timetoAdd)` recibe el segundo parametro de forma explicita en formato `HH:mm:ss` si juntamos todo esto nos deberia dar algo como lo siguiente

```
SELECT IF(TIME(tracked_arrival) = TIME(ADDTIME(time_window_end,"00:15:00"),1,0) AS A
```

Con esto si las horas son iguales retornara 1 de lo contrario retornara 0

## Referencias

[12.6 Date and Time Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time)

[MySQL ADDTIME() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_addtime.asp)

Comment: Hey, excelente respuesta, cambiaste la lógica de mi razonamiento totalmente, utilicé la siguiente sentencia para resolverlo:  if(Time(date_format(tracked_arrival, '%H:%i'))>=Time(ADDTIME(str_to_date(time_window_end, '%H:%i'),'00:15:00')),1,NULL) as "a"